# Using rnorm for a dataframe

Tags: r, random, montecarlo

I wanted to use rnorm function over a dataframe having e.g nrow=11451 elements. I don't know how to write the code to apply rnorm for each row leading to a sim-dataframe with nsim columns and nrow rows.

```
dfsim <- rnorm (n=nsim, mean=df[[?]], sd=df[[?]])
```

As an example:

```
> head(df)
An object of class "SpatialLinesDataFrame"
Slot "data":
           LINEARID            FULLNAME RTTYP MTFCC          M01         SD01 Nsim
10969 1104486135650       US Hwy 90 Alt     U S1200 0.0009886878 0.0001253361   10
10970 1104486135651       US Hwy 90 Alt     U S1200 0.0009831224 0.0001442643   10
10416 1102965182224 Southwest Fwy E Acc     M S1640 0.0010000000 0.0000000000   10
10494 1103342335512   Robin Hood Ct Pvt     M S1780 0.0010000000 0.0000000000   10
10493 1103342334514 Little John Way Pvt     M S1750 0.0010000000 0.0000000000   10
1847  1101842210421      Arrowood Cir N     M S1400 0.0010000000 0.0000000000   10
```

My expected result is to have ten more columns for each row including simulated values.

I used the following code but got "invalid argument error"

```
> dfnorm <- apply(df@data, 1, function(x) rnorm(x["Nsim"], mean=x["M01"], sd=x["SD01"]))
 Error in rnorm(x["Nsim"], mean = x["M01"], sd = x["SD01"]) : 
  invalid arguments
```

Since the dataframe is too large, I used the subset function to keep only three rows and save it into the .rdata file. Here is the link:
[df.rdata](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4zg20xp1r7vjmg1/df.RData?dl=0)

Comment: Actually for each row in df I have the mean and sd, and I want to call them in rnorm function.

Comment: Use dput(head(df)) instead of head(df)so we have a reproducible dataset

Comment: I added a link to the .rdata file. Thank you.

Comment: the answer has been updated

Comment: Thank you @DataTx!Really appreciated...

Comment: Yeah thank you again. Without no error! But as I mentioned in the @Tunn answer, the output is the dataFrame and I need to convert it spatialDataFrame (I mean attach the output to the input df).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your dataframe you need to add a column with the sample size like such:

```
 dataFrameApply <- data.frame(sampleSize = c(100,100,100),               
                            meanNum = c(1,2,3), sdNum = c(1,2,3))
      sampleSize meanNum sdNum
1        100       1     1
2        100       2     2
3        100       3     3
```

Then use apply to go over each row. The second argument can be 1 or 2 depending on whether to apply over row or column.

```
normalize <- apply(dataFrameApply, 1, function(x) rnorm(x[1], mean=x[2], sd=x[3]))
```

This worked for me on my machine

```
dfDataFrame  <- as.data.frame(df@data)
dataFrameSub <- dfDataFrame[,c(7,5,6)]
normalize    <- apply(dataFrameSub,    1, function(x) rnorm(x[1], mean=x[2], 
                sd=x[3]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I said I have the mean and sd for each row and i don't need to calculate them. So what should I do?

Comment: @Mohammad In the example data frame for the first row it specifies that you want a sample size of 100. The mean for that group is 1 and sd is 1. Those are actuals and not computed.

Comment: Thanks! I could go one step further. Is it important to add the column for sample size? I mean can we only use a constant nsim?

Comment: Also I'm working on spatial data frame so I need to put @data after dataFrameApply. But I get this error:  `Error in rnorm(n = nsim, mean = x[["M01"]], sd = x[["SD01"]]) :   invalid arguments`

Comment: Yes you need to add a sample size and it's not hard to add a column with the rep function. You need to also put an example data set with expected results

Comment: I edited the question. please check again. I'm still getting the error `invalid argument`. I think it's related to the type of dataframe.

Comment: If I don't use df@data I get the following error: `Error in as.vector(data) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector`

Answer (score 1):

Can do `pmap` from `purrr` package and build the rnorms right into your dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)
df@data <- df@data %>% 
  mutate(rnorms = pmap(list(Nsim, M01, SD01), function(n, mu, sd) rnorm(n, mu, sd)),
         rnorms = map_chr(rnorms, ~ paste(., collapse = " "))) %>% 
  bind_cols(., read.table(text = .$rnorms, sep = " ")) %>%
  select(-rnorms)
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! But it changes the spatialLinesDataFrame to data.frame. Is there any way to add the simulated values as new columns to the dataFrameApply?

Comment: Yes, but you're going to have different `Nsim` values right?

Comment: Actually no. Nsim is the same for all rows.

Comment: Added all the rnorms as columns.  Let me know if you want an explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked! But my only concern is that the final output should be a spatialDataFrame. I'm trying to convert it to spatialDataFrame.

Comment: Fixed in edit.  I used the file you hyperlinked.  This only modifies the `data.frame` piece of your `spatialDataFrame` so it keeps the rest intact.

Comment: Awesome! Everything is fixed.Thank you so much!